# Pomegranate aphids or something else

Tags: fruit-trees, pest-control, aphids, pomegranate

I bought this pomegranate plant a few days back. Plant was healthy but now I see this tiny white things on the plant, these could be aphids I am not sure. I have adde some snaps, can someone confirm this.

I have sprayed the plant with soap solution twice in the last week but the plants still have the infestation. Although the white color has turned to black.

I am planning for a neem spray in day or two.

Can someone guide me in right direction, the plant is losing a lot of leaves.

Images
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do a Neem dunk.  Paper plate sliced to the middle to go around the base of the plant and stop the soil from falling out...turn upside down and swish in the Neem mixture.  Turn right side up and allow to dry.  Is this plant indoors?  Did you use garden soil in your pots?  You have also got white fly which will be controlled by the Neem dip.  Your plants look quite, pale.  What have you used for fertilizer?  Weak plants are more susceptible to insect infestations.

Comment: Neem dunk!!! The plant is in my balcony and the pot is 12 inches wide. The plant is relatively large and the pot heavy. Will a neem spray (a vigorous one) suffice. I won’t be able to dip the plant by moving it.

Comment: Sorry, the Neem dunk ain't for you!  Grins!  Yes, spraying will work, get under the leaves for sure, the top of the soil, lightly.  Lay some newspaper down and gently put your pot on its side.  Spray till runoff and roll gently and spray again.  Do this at night, not during the day.  This is stinky stuff.  I hate the smell.  Wear gloves, long sleeve shirt.  I am sort of sensitive to this oh so 'organic' pesticide.  Works well however.  It is a contact pesticide not systemic.  I would cover the flowers with saranwrap prior to spraying until your plant has had time to dry...after standing it up.